# Verify string containing certain characters using regular expression in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a requirement in tcl where we need to accept a string from the user. The string must consist of at least 1 capital letter, 1 number and 1 special character.

Can anyone say what regular expression we should use?

Answer (score 1):

If your assignment states that you have to solve it in one go, sort the string's characters first. Then use a regular expression that looks for the kinds of characters you want in the order digit-uppercase-lowercase, allowing for other characters in between.

If you don't need to solve it with one application of `regexp`, test three times, one for each of the kinds of character you want. If all tests succeed, you have a strong password.